# Add value to DataPoint by user

Tags: android-graphview

How to add values to `DataPoint` which to be plotted in case I do not know number of possible entries?

```
     DataPoint[] db = new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(5,4),
            new DataPoint(2,4),
            new DataPoint(4,4),
            new DataPoint(9,0),
            new DataPoint(0,3)} ;
    PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint>(db) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a call to this method before you add DataPoint array to LineGraphSeries.

```
   private void generateDataForGraph() {
    int size = Amount.size();
     values = new DataPoint[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        Integer xi = Integer.parseInt(Dates.get(i));
        Integer yi = Integer.parseInt(Amount.get(i));
       DataPoint v = new DataPoint(xi, yi);
        values[i] = v;
    }
 series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(values);
        graph2.addSeries(series);
}
```